# How to pass code to attached screen

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, r

I am running an R script using a Linux Workstation. I am new to Linux - thanks for your patience!

I first ran `screen` before running my R script, `Rscript myRscript.R`

After checking in on my script using `screen -r '27756.pts-9.mimas'` I saw that it was having issue and used `CTRL + C` to stop it.

I am hoping that I can save the workspace from that R session, though. Normally, I would use this line of code `save.image(file = "master_BIOMOD_data_workspace")`. Is it possible to enter the R session that was taking place in the screen and pass it that line of code?

This is what `screen -r` currently returns.

[image]